# autocomplete соеденить две функции

Tags: jquery

есть две функции которые по одной в автокомлите работают, как их соеденить что бы обе работали?

```
$('.qwerty').autocomplete({
    //функция ограничения вывода
    /*source: function(request, response) {
     var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(data, request.term);
     response(results.slice(0, 5));
     },*/
    //функция поиска с первой буквы
    source: function (req, responseFn) {
        var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);
        var matcher = new RegExp("^" + re, "i");
        var a = $.grep(data, function (item, index) {
            return matcher.test(item);
        });
        responseFn(a);
    },

    minLength: 1

})
```

Comment: Уточните свой вопрос и опишите проблему детальнее пожалуйста

Comment: мне нужно что бы в автокомлите не выводилось больше 5 записей, и поиск осуществлялся с первой буквы в поисковом запросе, эти функции есть и по одной они работают, как сделать что бы обе работали?

Comment: Т.е вам надо чтобы два скрипта сработали асинхронно?

Comment: да именно этого я пытаюсь добиться, у вопроси эти скрипты имеются

Comment: Думаю, тут Вы сможете найти ответ на свой вопрос http://stackoverflow.com/a/9516967/4713486